# (windows server 2016) (python/Django) Couldn't import Django

Tags: python, django, import, python-import

The full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core'; 'django' is not a package

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

- I have tried adding django directly to the PYTHONPATH, no dice
- I have created a virtual environment and installed django in it, still nothing
- According to pip freeze I got Django 2.1.2 installed
- I'm pretty sure I'm using python 3.7.0
- Apparently I can import django just fine (by just typing "import django" in an empty test.py file), but when I try to import django.core it gives me the following error:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test.py", line 7, in 
      import django.core
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core'; 'django' is not a      package

(stackoverflow won't let me format it as code for some reason)

Comment: Do you run `manage.py` with `python3` (by default it will run with `python2` I think). So `python3 manage.py runserver --settings=some_settings`.

Comment: I installed python 3 directly. Given that python3 doesn't work I assume that python stands for python3 specifically.

Comment: What if you run `python --version`?

Comment: python 3.7.0 both in general and in my virtualenv

Comment: Nevermind I was just told I'm an idiot and I shouldn't be messing with django when I barely know what a class is. I'm closing this. Thanks for the help though.